# Recursive component in laravel-livewire

Tags: laravel-livewire

I want use recursive for categories, one  recursive  component. I don't know do it. Please help me.

**Database categories**: id - name - parent_id

Code in **admin.category** blade:

```
<tbody>
 @foreach ($categories as $category)
   @if ($category->parent_id == $parent_id)
     @livewire('admin.category.tr', ['category' => $category], key($category->id))
   @endif
 @endforeach
</tbody>
```

Code in **admin.category.tr** blade:

```
<tr>
 <td class="text-center">{{ $category->id }}</td>
 <td><h5>{{ $category->name }}</h5></td> 
</tr>
```

I try write one blade new, with name is tr-recursive

Code in **admin.category** blade:

```
<tbody>
@livewire('admin.category.tr-recursive',
          [ 'categories' => $categories,
            'parent_id' => null
          ],key(rand())
          )
</tbody>
```

Code in **admin.category.tr-recursive**:

Class:

```
public $categories, $parent_id,$icon='';
public function render()
{
  return view('livewire.admin.category.tr-recursive');
}
```

Blade:

```
<div>
    @foreach ($categories as $category)
        @if ($category->parent_id == $parent_id)
            <tr>
                <td class="text-center">{{ $category->id }}</td>
                <td><h5>{{ $icon.$category->name }}</h5></td>
            </tr>
            @livewire(
                'admin.category.tr-recursive',
                [
                    'categories' => $categories,
                    'parent_id' => $category->id,
                    'icon' => "$icon---",
                ],
                key($category->id),
            )
        @endif
    @endforeach
</div>
```

So, it is warning *"Multiple root elements detected. This is not supported"*

How to fix warning it ?

Answer (score 0):

First you have to have a recursive component, i won't use the exact same category stuff that you did, but you will get the picture.

`recursive-category.blade.php`

```
@props(['category', 'level' = 0])

<li>
    <p>{{ $category->name }}</p>
    @php
       $children = \App\Models\Category::where('parent_id', $category->id))->get();
    @endphp

    @if($children->count() > 0))
       <ul>
          @foreach($children as $child)
             <x-recursive-category :category="$child" :level="$level + 1" />
          @endforeach
       </ul>
    @endif
</li>
```

Then in your navigation or something you only render the top-level categories that don't have a parent.

`navigation.blade.php`

```
<ul>
   @php
      $categories = \App\Models\Category::where('parent_id', null)->get();
   @endphp

   @foreach($categories as $category)
      <x-recursive-category :$category />
   @endforeach
</ul>
```

When you want to use livewire, you just replace the component calls for livewire calls and you are good to go.